# If and else if with strcmp sequence fault / overlapping

Tags: c, string, strcmp

at first I'll post the needed code.

```
#define STRING_LEFT        "05000858FB"
#define STRING_RIGHT       "05000B3E45"
#define STRING_LENGTH_MAX   16

char stringname[STRING_LENGTH_MAX+1];

if(strcmp(stringname, STRING_LEFT)==0)
{
// do stuff A here
}
else if(strcmp(stringname, STRING_RIGHT)==0)
{
// do stuff B here
}
```

stringname is triggered via a sensor that transfers a hexadecimal value and needs to be compared with STRING_LEFT and STRING_RIGHT followed by different actions. When stringname and STRING_LEFT are equal (==0) it does stuff A. If I activate STRING_RIGHT the next time, it does again stuff A. When I use RIGHT a second time, it does B. If I use LEFT again, it does B, a second time A. So the function is always like 'one-event-behind'....and I don't want to have that. How can I avoid this?

TIA

Comment: `stringname` is variable as well as function also in your code. where is `stringname` function? is any typo?

Comment: Yeah, editet that, was just a typo here, not in the original code

Comment: Your description doesn't make sense. Possibly the contents of `stringname` actually are not what you think they are, but there's no way we can tell based on just what you have posted. Please post a sample program that doesn't rely on any external input (e.g. hardcode some sensor responses) and shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an important typo in your code:

```
else if(stringname(stringname, STRING_RIGHT)==0)
```

should probably be

```
else if(strcmp(stringname, STRING_RIGHT)==0)
```

(unless stringname is also a function besides a variable; in that case you should post that code, but that would be **bad practice**)

Comment: the original actually should not compile; even if there is a function `stringname` , one name will shadow the other (there's no "overloading" of names based on context in C).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do following:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRING_LEFT        "05000858FB"
#define STRING_RIGHT       "05000B3E45"
#define STRING_LENGTH_MAX   16

#define STRING_TO_COMPARE "05000858FB"

int main()
{
    char stringname[STRING_LENGTH_MAX+1];
    /* initialize the string to compare */
    strcpy(stringname, STRING_TO_COMPARE);

    if(strcmp(stringname, STRING_LEFT)==0)
    {
    // do stuff A here
    }
    /* call strcmp */
    else if(strcmp(stringname, STRING_RIGHT)==0)
    {
    // do stuff B here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In that example, the `stringname` contains the same string than `STRING_LEFT`, so the program will execute `stuff B`.
Of course you will have to set the `stringname` with the needed string.

Comment: Why do you use STRING_TO_COMPARE that has the same values as STRING_LEFT? Sry, I don't get it :/

Comment: it's only to have a success, I add a note

Comment: I mean by success, to enter a case